# Partially working function for creating thumbnails

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I have a partially working function for making thumbnails but 10% of the images doesn't get created as thumbnails, and they're the same exact 10%. The other 90% works. I'm not sure why though. Please take a look at my code:

```
<?php

$image = "511photo.jpg";

if ($image) {
make_thumb("uploads", "thumbnails", $image, 500);
}

function make_thumb($imageFrom, $imageTo, $image, $thumbWidth) {

/* read the source image */
$getFrom = $imageFrom."/".$image;

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($getFrom);
$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$thumbHeight = floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);

/* copy source image at a resized size */
imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $width, $height);

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */

$dest = $imageTo."/".$image;
imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);

} //end of function make_thumb($imageFrom, $imageTo, $image, $thumbWidth)

?>
```

Note: Here's a couple of other $image that doesn't work:

```
"434cute-anime-couple-drawing-on-tumblr.png"
"503anime_head_vectorized_by_cona_cru-d784ls0.png"
```

Note: Yes, I am sure that they are all in the uploads folder - I've checked and double checked so honestly, right now I'm so confuse...

Comment: you are using imagejpeg function for png extension it will not support please look try to find how to upload for png files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` for `png` image. You need to use `imagecreatefrompng()` for these images.

```
$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($getFrom);
```

For checking image type you can use [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) function :

```
$imageType =  exif_imagetype($getFrom);

if($imageType == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    //It's PNG
} elseif($imageType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    //It's JPEG
} //You can check more types here.
```

Comment: How come I'm able to make thumbnails from most jpg, then? And 511photo.jpg is jpg, but I couldn't make a thumbnail from it.

Comment: Can u Pls add the photo here or give us a link?

Comment: It's a jpg file type, but suddenly I'm able to make a thumbnail out of it when I added the png function. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, I'm able to use imagejpeg() to create from png once I use the imagecreatefrompng(). Why is that?

Comment: What I see is that the image you provided above is a PNG image, someone just changed the file extension from png to jpg. And it is working after you added my code, because `exif_imagetype()` will find it as png even if it has jpg extension.

Answer (score 1):

check file type and add this code with imagejpeg function in a condition its an example add your variables and values

```
if($fileType=="image/png"){
   $im=ImageCreateFromPNG($add); 
   $width=ImageSx($im);              // Original picture width is stored
   $height=ImageSy($im);             // Original picture height is stored
   $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);                 
   imageCopyResized($newimage,$im,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$width,$height);
   ImagePng($newimage,$tsrc);
   chmod("$tsrc",0777);
}
```

Comment: but 511photo.jpg is jpg and it does not work even though other jpgs worked

Comment: how can I make it support all image types?